# Получение информации из двух БД в одну модель

Tags: php, model, connection, laravel-8

Пытаюсь объединить информацию из двух БД внутри одной модели `User` без sql-запросов `update`.

#### Класс пользователя

1. В `$fillable` указаны поля, которые должны заполняться данными из двух БД.
2. Поля `name` и `password` заполняются при при входе пользователя в систему из первой базы. **(успешно)**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'auth';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'password', 'group', 'prefix', 'suffix'];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->table = config('database.connections.auth.table');
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
}
```

#### Event listener

- Поля `group`, `prefix` и `suffix` должны получаться при использовании второго подключения (`connection('perm')`) и поля `name` из первого, однако сохранить информацию в поля БЕЗ sql-запросов `update` я не могу.

```
Event::listen(function (Authenticated $event) {
    $user = $event->user;
    $perms_table = config('database.connections.perms.table');

    $uuid = Uuid::generate(3, "SUUID:".strtolower($user->name));

    $result = DB::connection('perms')->table($perms_table)
        ->select('data')
        ->where('name', '=', $uuid)
        ->first();

    $data = json_decode($result->data, true);

    $group = $data['userGroup'];
    $prefix = $data['prefix'];
    $suffix = $data['suffix'];


    $result = UserGroup::getGroupByName($group);
    if (!$result){
        echo 'null';
        # Auth::logout();
        return;
    }

    Session::put('group', $group);
    Session::put('prefix', $prefix);
    Session::put('suffix', $suffix);

    dd(Session::all());
});
```

---

Вместо `Session::put()` должно быть `$user->поле = значение`, однако сохранить обновленные данные невозможно без sql-запроса `update`, который будет использовать основное подключение, а там полей `group` и тд нет, что черевато ошибкой:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'group' in 'field list' 
(SQL: update `users` set `group` = project, `prefix` = тест_префикс, 
`suffix` = тест_суффикс, `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-04-17 20:55:57 where `id` = 1)
```

**Вопрос**: как лучше всего реализовать желаемый функционал и есть ли вообще такая возможность?

Comment: Вы хотите с двух баз одновременно при запросе к модели получить данные? Или у Вас 2 соединения, и в зависимости от выбранного подтягиваются данные одной из баз? По коду вообще не очень понятно, чего Вы пытаетесь добиться (ещё и sqlinjection допускаете)...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Именно с двух баз одновременно. С первой базы я получаю имя пользователя и пароль для авторизации, со второй - конкретные данные(группа, префикс и тд), используя полученное имя с первой базы.
Обновил информацию о вопросе, прошу прощения.

Comment: Получается авторизация по первой бд а остальное действие через вторую бд? Сделайте свой драйвер авторизации, если у вас одна база только логин пароль